# Can't see logs from VS Code with ASP.NET (Core) using Docker Logs

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, serilog, vscode-debugger

I've created a .NET 5 API project (shortname = webapi) from the dotnet CLI, opened the project in VS Code, added the "required assets to build/debug" (.vscode launch and tasks.json files), and then added Docker support using the command-palette "Docker: Add Docker Files to Project" item -- defaults were used with every step.  I've made no other initial changes (and am using the https flavor of the project).

When I debug the project, I can see the first few log entries (nothing past initial startup) in the Debug Console, but not from the Docker Logs -- either from Docker Desktop or the `docker logs` CLI command.  The project runs fine and the Swagger UI works and the API behaves fine.  But I can't see any docker logs.

I've run this on two Windows machines and a Mac with the same behavior.

I've also tried adding Serilog and writing to the console, and this fixes the "no logs past startup" issue - meaning that I can see all of the appropriate logs in the Debug Console within VS Code, but I still cannot see any logs in Docker Desktop or the CLI.

NOTE:  I *can* see the container itself, and "stats" and other info from the docker tooling -- just not the logs.

Am I just missing a setting somewhere or a docker option that should be set within VS Code?

When I do the same things from Visual Studio the docker logs show up fine.

Specific steps:

- `dotnet new webapi -o <someprojectname>`
- open VS Code in the folder for the new project
- Add the "required assets to build and debug"
- Invoke the `Docker: Add Docker Files to Workspace` command (Linux containers) with all defaults
- Launch the Docker profile

Problem: Startup logs show up in Debug Console, but no more after that, AND logs don't show up in Docker tooling at all.  Adding Serilog (with Console Sink) fixes the "startup only logs" issue, but the logs STILL don't show up in Docker tooling.

Here is the debug console:
[image]

I would expect to see those `info` logs in the docker tooling, and then some similar entries as I execute requests against the API.  If I change the logging to Serilog and use the Console sink, the Debug Console will then show ALL of the entries (including when I execute requests against the API), but docker tooling still remains empty.

Comment: What are the startup logs that you're correctly seeing, and what other logs do you expect? What does the code look like that logs additional bits after startup that you're expecting? I'm curious if the log levels is an issue here.

Comment: Updated question with some details.  I haven't modified the original "out of the box" webapi project.  And since I'm getting the info entries for startup I would expect to be getting them on requests (confirmed when I use serilog with console sink).

Comment: if `docker logs` doesn't show you anything, then the program you are running in the container simply doesn't produce any output.

Comment: This is the "out of the box" webapi from the MS templates -- if I `docker build` the same thing and run it using the `docker run` command the logs will show up.  I suspect it has something to do with the way VS Code is set to debug the project.

Comment: I'm curious if @DanielW. is on to something here, did you try seeing logs without it running in Docker - do you see logs then?

Comment: yeah -- the logs are there and they are better with Serilog and the console sink.  But no matter what i do from vs code, they don't show up in docker logs.  If it do a docker build and docker run then they work fine.

Comment: I think I might know what's going on but still haven't solved.  When running from Visual Studio, these arguments get added to the end of the docker run command:  `--entrypoint tail helloworldapi:dev -f /dev/null` and they don't get added in the debug run command from VS Code.  Wondering about the `dockerRun` settings that might this done.